# Python3 dictionary values being overwritten

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I’m having a problem with a dictionary.  I"m using Python3.  I’m sure there’s something easy that I’m just not seeing.

I’m reading lines from a file to create a dictionary.  The first 3 characters of each line are used as keys (they are unique).  From there, I create a list from the information in the rest of the line.  Each 4 characters make up a member of the list.  Once I’ve created the list, I write to the directory with the list being the value and the first three characters of the line being the key.

The problem is, each time I add a new key:value pair to the dictionary, it seems to overlay (or update) the values in the previously written dictionary entries.  The keys are fine, just the values are changed.  So, in the end, all of the keys have a value equivalent to the list made from the last line in the file.

I hope this is clear.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

A snippet of the code is below

```
formatDict = dict()  
sectionList = list()  
for usableLine in formatFileHandle:  
    lineLen = len(usableLine)  
    section = usableLine[:3]  
    x = 3  
    sectionList.clear()  
    while x < lineLen:  
        sectionList.append(usableLine[x:x+4])  
        x += 4
    formatDict[section] = sectionList  
for k, v in formatDict.items():  
    print ("for key= ", k, "value =", v)  
formatFileHandle.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You always clear, then append and then insert the same `sectionList`, that's why it always overwrites the entries - because you told the program it should.

Always remember: In Python assignment **never** makes a copy!

### Simple fix

Just insert a copy:

```
formatDict[section] = sectionList.copy()    # changed here
```

Instead of inserting a reference:

```
formatDict[section] = sectionList
```

### Complicated fix

There are lots of things going on and you could make it "better" by using functions for subtasks like the grouping, also files should be opened with `with` so that the file is closed automatically even if an exception occurs and `while` loops where the end is known should be avoided.

Personally I would use code like this:

```
def groups(seq, width):
    """Group a sequence (seq) into width-sized blocks. The last block may be shorter."""
    length = len(seq)
    for i in range(0, length, width):   # range supports a step argument!
        yield seq[i:i+width]

# Printing the dictionary could be useful in other places as well -> so
# I also created a function for this.
def print_dict_line_by_line(dct):  
    """Print dictionary where each key-value pair is on one line."""
    for key, value in dct.items():
        print("for key =", key, "value =", value)

def mytask(filename):
    formatDict = {}
    with open(filename) as formatFileHandle:
        # I don't "strip" each line (remove leading and trailing whitespaces/newlines)
        # but if you need that you could also use:
        # for usableLine in (line.strip() for line in formatFileHandle):
        # instead.
        for usableLine in formatFileHandle:
            section = usableLine[:3]
            sectionList = list(groups(usableLine[3:]))
            formatDict[section] = sectionList
    # upon exiting the "with" scope the file is closed automatically!
    print_dict_line_by_line(formatDict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mytask('insert your filename here')
```

Comment: thanks much.  Your simple fix did the trick.  I continue to review your explanation of the problem, but i'll get there!  Also, thanks for the "complicated fix".  There are good suggestions in there for me to consider.

Comment: @BillMorgan No problem. Please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code here by using a `with` statement to auto close the file and chunk the remainder of the line into groups of four, avoiding the re-use of a single list.

```
from itertools import islice

with open('somefile') as fin:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in fin)
    format_dict = {
        line[:3]: list(iter(lambda it=iter(line[3:]): ''.join(islice(it, 4)), '')) 
        for line in stripped
    }

for key, value in format_dict.items():
    print('key=', key, 'value=', value)
```

Comment: Really? You would use `list(iter(lambda it=iter(row[3:]): ''.join(islice(it, 4)), ''))` in your code? :)

Comment: @MSeifert I'd wrapper it, but that's an exercise for the reader... (and hey - it works doesn't it? :p)

Comment: okay, good point - I like what you did there with the mutable default. However that probably will throw a `NameError` at `row`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MSeifert bah... I tend to call things `row`, then think it looks daft when posting and half rename them to `line`... good catch - thanks.