# Why is this loop duplicating the latest entry instead of appending it to the list?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

This is a small snippet of a larger piece of code.

It’s supposed to put data into `temp_dict` and then add it to the full list of dictionaries `list_of_dicts`. Then it loops, clears `temp_dict`, then puts new data into `temp_dict` and adds that new dictionary to `list_of_dicts`.

So for this code example:

```
list_of_dicts = []
blank = {}
temp_dict = {}
 
for i in range(0,5):
    temp_dict = blank
    print(i)
    temp_dict['key'] = i
 
    list_of_dicts.append(temp_dict)
 
print(list_of_dicts)
```

The result should be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
[{'key': 0}, {'key':1},{'key':2},{'key':3},{'key':4}]
```

But instead I get:

```
0
1
2
3
4
[{'key': 4}, {'key': 4}, {'key': 4}, {'key': 4}, {'key': 4}]
```

I feel like there’s a really simple fix to this that I’m just not seeing.

Answer (score 3):

```
temp_dict = blank
```

That is the reason.  You're modifying and reusing the `blank` object every time through the loop, and your list ends up with multiple identical references to `blank`.

Just use `temp_dict = {}` instead.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: [Python3 dictionary values being overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919085/python3-dictionary-values-being-overwritten?rq=1)

> Always remember: In Python assignment never makes a copy!
>
> Simple fix Just insert a copy:
>
> ```
> formatDict[section] = sectionList.copy()    # changed here
> ```
>
> Instead of inserting a reference:
>
> ```
> formatDict[section] = sectionList
> ```

Using .copy() produces the result I need.

```
temp_dict = blank.copy()
```

I wasn't aware of how Python "copies" objects.